# Keyboard on Android phone disappears after starting VNC server, and reappears only after restart

Tags: keyboard, vnc, gboard

As the title says, I want to remote control my Android phone (LG-F160K) using a VNC server. I tried `droid VNC server` and `VNC server`. I can connect to my Android phone, but after connection is made, the original keyboard (I am using Google Chinese IME keyboard) is gone and replaced with a single row with a few buttons. The keyboard cannot be restored after I close the server, and it restores only after I restart the machine.

Considering that as a nuisance, I wonder if there is anyway to restore the keyboard automatically after closing the VNC server?